# Scrapy - unable to format properly csv

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am currently training myself on Scrapy, and I would like to format my export properly.
Here is the output : (a french well known classified ads website is scraped for training)

```
"600 €,,,850 €,,,850 €,,,850 €,,770 €,,,600 €,,,600 €,,,60 €,,,782 €,,,670 €,,,700 €,,,936 €,,,730 €,,,450 €,,,800 €,,,680 €,,,865 €,,,790 €,,,880 €,,,850 €,,,900 €,,,813 €,,,850 €,,,795 €,,,560 €,,,900 €,,,750 €,,,950 €,,,390 €,,,875 €,,,650 €,,,799 €,,,825 €,,,695 €,,,790 €,,","Studio meublé 10m² GAITE PARIS 14e,,Très joli studio paris 14,,Studio meublé avec mezzanine Porte d'Orléans,,Studio 1 pièce 33 m²,,STUDIO 20m² - Métro ALESIA -St Pierre de Montrouge,,Studio meublé porte d'Orléans,,Location courte durée Studio 14ème Alésia,,Studio paris 14eme libre dec et janv/nuit,,Appartement 2 pièces 29 m²,,Appartement Alésia / 14ème arrondissement,,Studio meublé a louer de suite,,STUDIO rue Pernety 75014,,Studio 15m2 - Paris 14ème,,Appartement Paris 14eme 35m² 1- 4 personnes,,Beau 2 pieces 14eme arrondissement,,Petit studio a louer,,Studio au coeur de paris- montparnasse,,Studio Paris 14e à louer,,Studio 27m² meublé,,Studio 1 pièce 22 m²,,Studio,,Studio 1 pièce 31 m²,,Studio 1 pièce 25 m²,,Appartement 1 pièce 23 m²,,Studette meublé 9m² ALESIA,,Studio 25 m2 à Paris 14,,Appartement 17m proche métro Glacière,,2 Pièces au calme proche Montparnasse,,Studette paris 14eme,,STUDIO 26M2 PARIS 14e ALESIA,,STUDETTE 16m2 RUE D ALESIA 650 EUROS,,Studio meublé et équipé résidence Consul,,Studio 22,5 m2 Métro Pernety,,Appartement 1 pièce 19 m²,,Studio meublé avec 2 balcons Montparnasse Pernety,",""
```

So basically I have :

```
Price1,Price2,Price3... description1,description2,description3..
```

I would like to have :

```
Price 1, Description1
Price 2, Description2
```

etc.

Here is my code :

```
class LbcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'lbc'

start_urls = ['https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/offres/ile_de_france/?th=1&location=Paris%2075014&parrot=0&mre=950&sqe=4&ret=2']
# j'étais en train de me mettre sur lbc pour scrapper les pages
def parse(self, response):
    # extraction des infos de la page 1

    yield {
        # extraction du titre
        # 'title': response.css(
        #    'a.list_item.clearfix.trackable section.item_infos h2.item_title::text').re(r'\s{20,}(.*)'),
        'title': response.css(
            'a.list_item.clearfix.trackable section.item_infos h2.item_title::text').re(r'\s{20,}(.*)'),
        # extraction prix
        'Price': response.css(
            'a.list_item.clearfix.trackable section.item_infos h3.item_price::text').re(r'\s{20,}(.*)'),
        }

    # visite des pages suivantes
    # avec for on extrait de la liste chaque url pour la parser
    # on ajoute http car pour une raison inconnue elle ne fait pas partie de l'extract?
    next_page = response.xpath('//a[@id="next"]/@href').extract()
    if next_page is not None:
        # modification pour avoir plusieurs url
        for href in next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request('http:' + href, callback=self.parse)
        # next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        #yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

My questions are the following :

- Why Price values come first when my code puts the calling in last position?
- How can I add a "\n" to create a new line at each call ?

Best,

Comment: Which is the code that instantiate and uses `class LbcSpider()`?

(See [ask] and [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrapy extractor generates a list of all the scraped items.

I think it would be easier to separate the scraping and the returning of the items, in order to properly format your output file, like this:

```
def parse(self, response): 
    title = # Scrape the titles
    Price = # Scrape the prices
    result = zip(title, Price)
    for title, Price in result:
        item = LbcItem()
        item['title'] = title
        item['Price'] = Price
        yield item
```

This way you first scrape all the prices and titles, storing them in their separate lists, before zipping them and iterating over the zipped `result`-variable.

This way you assign each item and yield it separately, which should result in the way you want it.

Additionally you can define the order in which to export your items in a csv-export by defining `FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS` in your project settings (see [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#csv))